# Spring Boot 2 / Spring Security 5: Unable to obtain OAUTH2 token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Framework: Spring Boot 2 (Spring 5)

I am following the instructions [on the Spring Boot 2 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server) on how to have a service providing OAUTH2 tokens.

You can see the code here on GitHub. (EDIT: Link removed. It was no longer valid after updating that branch.)

Whatever secret / user ID / password I send to `/oauth/token`, I get a 403 with a plain text response: `CSRF Token has been associated to this client`.

Example:

```
$ curl client:secret@localhostlocalhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password - d username=user -d password=pwd -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'client'
> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 46
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 46 out of 46 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
CSRF Token has been associated to this client%
```

The overall reaction is a mystery.

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to the Spring Framework and find it difficult to get working tutorial or reference material. I hope it is something "stupid" I haven't seen.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @dur : Sorry about this half-edit. That came from the `client:secret@` before the hostname in the CURL command. I removed it from the CURL, but forgot that question there. In both cases (with or without that header), the behaviour is the same.